# orientdb lost Lucene Indexes

Tags: lucene, orientdb

I'm learning to use orientdb. When I create a class and built 80 million pieces of data with "lucene full text index", I found that when the database is running for some time, the index will be baffling loss of data can not check out the cause, who can tell me the reason?

Comment: which version of OrientDB are you using? can you provide the schema and some sample data?

Comment: I used orientdb(v 2.1.5).I create class Message. Message'Properties is like {Name:account,Type:LINK,Linked_class:Account;
 Name:content,Type:STRING;.....}.Message'Index is like {name:Message.content,Type:FULLTEXT,Properties:["content"],Engine:LUCENE}